# Query for custom post type objects in a taxonomy and with a meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, meta-query, tax-query

I want fetch all posts from the post type `book` in the custom taxonomy `book_tags` with the meta key `lang` and the meta value `en`.

My code:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => 40,
    'paged'          => "$paged", 

    'meta_query'     => array(
        array( 
            'key'     => 'lang',
            'value'   => 'en',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'book_tags',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => get_queried_object()->slug
        )
    )
);

$additional_loop = new WP_Query($args); 

while ($additional_loop->have_posts()) : 
    $additional_loop->the_post();
```

This doesn’t work? Why?

If I remove "meta_query" it works. Is there a bug in "meta_query"?

Comment: Please explain precisely what you are trying to do and what isn't working (compared to what you are expecting)... because it is possible there is a better way to do what you want. For example filtering `pre_get_posts` is a very common solution that people overlook when trying to modify a loop. Though for a start, I'd guess that `"$paged"` is wrong (since the variable is in quotes) as might also be `get_queried_object()->slug`.

Comment: if I remove "meta_query" then It'work, because I think "meta_query" have bug. I want display all custom post "lang=en". Sorry my bad EL

Comment: Your English is fine, but you aren't saying much for me to go on. :)  You want to show all custom posts with lang=en for a specific term. Is this on a custom taxonomy archive? Custom post archive? There is no bug with `meta_query`.  Please edit your question to provide more details about what you are trying to do.. and where.

Comment: First, Thank you so much. I want to show all custom posts with lang=en on a custom taxonomy archive. Plz help me, and what's your email address? Nice to meet you, friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your comment, you said that you just want posts with meta key `lang=en` on a custom taxonomy page, the easiest way to do that would be to filter the query with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) before it is run.

```
function wpa_107371_meta_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // only change the query on a custom taxonomy
    // can check for a specific taxonomy if desired
    if ( is_tax() ) {
        //define our meta query
              $meta_query = array(
                  array(           // needs this nested array syntax to work
                    'key'    => 'lang',
                    'value'  => 'en',
                    'compare'=> '=',
                  ),
              );
         $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        return;
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_107371_meta_query' );
```